# What's the easiest way to transfer data from one table/Model to a different one for a beginner?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Apologies in advance for the huge wall of text, but I couldn't come up with a way to present my question in a shorter form because of the context-specific nature of it.**

**Please scroll down past the dotted line below if you'd like to skip my context intro:**

I'm doing a coding challenge as my first Laravel application wherein I'm required to set up an attendance tracker/time tracker (Displaying how much time  specific employees spent at work each day (Between a Check-In and Check-Out).

I'm a complete beginner (Going through Laravel 5.7 from Scratch On Laracasts Right now), so I'm looking for a solution/code approach that'd be within the scope of my current knowledge, and not something that I haven't learned on Laracasts yet.

Basically It'd be preferable for me to be pointed to a solution with syntax and methods that were shown until episode 20 on Laracasts (Basic Routing, Basic Controller usage, Basic Resource Controller usage, get & post, patch, delete methods, VERY BASIC eloquent relationships (Only know belongsTo  & hasMany relationships).

Note that it's simply PREFERABLE to stick within these methods, but other solutions are more than welcome.

**- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -**

Summary of the situation is, I have an html table where I want to display the attendance statistics of Employees. I have an **"Employee Management"** page (/employees/manage view) where I can add new employees and save them in the "Current Employees" table.

Snippet from the /employees/manage view:

```
<div class="table_container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        . . . . . . . . .. 

        @foreach($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $employee->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
                <th>{{ $employee->position }}</th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

code from the EmployeesController:

```
public function manage()
{
    $employees = Employee::all();
    return view('employees.manage', compact('employees'));
}



public function store()
{

    $employee = new Employee();

    $employee->name = request('name');
    $employee->position = request('position');

    $employee->save();

    return redirect('/employees/manage');
}
```

I also have an **"Attendance Management"** page (/attendants/manage/ view), where I basically select available employees from a  form type. I then plan to either "check in" or "check out" employees via respective buttons.

```
<option selected>Select an Employee</option>
@foreach($attendants as $attendant)
    <option value="{{ $attendant->name }}">{{ $attendant->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

How should I go about including available employees into the select form? I've been thinking about making an eloquent relationship between **Employee** and **Attendant** models:

```
class Attendant extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

Here's the attendants migration:

```
{
    Schema::create('attendants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
        $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')>on('employees');

        . . . . .
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

So, basically, my question is, how would I go about listing the available employees inside the select form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actualy you dont need seperate tables for that. Just adding one status column easier i think.
id - name - position - working_status

If you must still work on seperate tables relationship will be good.
if relationship does return instance that mean is this employe is working. If its not employee is available.This logic works too.

Answer (score 1):

/employees/manage view listing : fine

EmployeesController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Use validation 
    Employee::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('employees.manage'); //Try to use route
}
```

for HTML Form use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) it will reduce your code. after adding laravel form collective

```
{!! Form::select('attendants', $attendants, $selected_val,['id'=>'id','class'=>'class']) !!}
```

One line code for select box and options

use [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)